# Sum columns, count rows, with multiple tables to display data altogether

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a complex SQL problem outlined below, with the following tables and data:

Orders table:

```
OrderId    ClientId   CompanyId
--------------------------------
25          2           NULL
26          NULL        1 
27          3           NULL
28          3           NULL
29          NULL        3

Billing table                  Forwards table

OrderId    Amount PaidFull     OrderId    Amount  PaidFull
--------------------------     ---------------------------
25         $100    False         26        $25    False
26         $50     False         27        $50    False
27         $100    False         27        $50    False
28         $100    False         29        $50    False
29         $100    True


Client table                 Company table

ClientId     ClientName      CompanyId      CompanyName
-----------------------      ---------------------------
1            AClient          1              ACompany
2            BClient          2              BCompany
3            CClient          3              CCompany
```

I want to display the data in a table like below, with each company or client total billing summed and rows counted. And each company or client forwards summed and rows counted, with it being ordered alphabetical by the combination of Client and Company Name together:

```
Billing  Qty   Forwards Qty   Client/Company Name
--------------------------------------------------
$50       1    $25       1     ACompany
$100      1    $0        0     BClient
$200      2    $100      2     CClient
$0        0    $50       1     CCompany
```

The problem is that using my SQL query below, I'm getting duplicate values summing the billing table, as it is summing billing table OrderId 29 for $100, although it is marked PaidFull = True. Also, it is not ordering alphabetical by the combination of the client and company tables, it is separating them first, and then ordering them.

```
Select 
    Sum(b.Amount) As TotalAmount, 
    Count(b.Amount) As Count1, 
    Sum(f.Amount) As TotalAmountf, 
    Count(f.Amount) As Count2,
    d.ClientName, c.CompanyName
From
    Orders a 
Left Join 
    Billing b On a.OrderId = b.OderId And b.PaidFull = 'False'
Left Join 
    Forwards f On a.OrderId = f.OderId And f.PaidFull = 'False'
Left Join 
    Client d On a.ClientId = d.ClientId
Left Join 
    Company c On a.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
Where 
    (b.FaidFull = 'False' Or f.PaidFull = 'False')
Group by 
    ClientName, CompanyName
Order by 
    ClientName, CompanyName
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the `Billing` and `Forward` tables - How do you have 2 entries in the forward table for the same `OrderId` (and could the same happen in Billing? What could, conceivably show up there and how should your query deal with it?

Comment: Your answer worked. I just added, after the Group by, "Having Sum(B.Amount) >0 Or Sum(F.Amount) >0" In order to not select rows that have PaidFull=True. Because it was selected rows that were PaidFull=True. To answer your question, yes there could be multiple same OrderIds in Billing and Forwards tables. This is working as of right now, and I hope it stays that way!

Comment: I'm really not sure why you would need that since it should be taken out in the CTEs. I used your extra `HAVING` clause in the sample dataset and it returned the same table. But, assuming your production data needs it, I'm glad it's working for you, just not sure at all why you would need to add that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not really sure about your table structure for `Billing` and `Forwards`, the easiest way to accomplish this would be to use CTEs to first sum all the values in those 2 tables, then just use those values in your final query like so:

```
WITH TotalBilling
AS
(
    SELECT
         OrderId
        ,SUM(Amount) Amount
    FROM
        Billing
    WHERE
        PaidFull = 'FALSE'
    GROUP BY
        OrderId
),

TotalForwards
AS
(
    SELECT
         OrderId
        ,SUM(Amount) Amount
    FROM
        Forwards
    WHERE
        PaidFull = 'FALSE'
    GROUP BY
        OrderId
)

SELECT
     SUM(B.Amount)                           AS Billing
    ,COUNT(B.OrderId)                        AS Qty
    ,SUM(F.Amount)                           AS Forwards
    ,COUNT(F.OrderId)                        AS Qty
    ,COALESCE(Cl.ClientName, Co.CompanyName) AS "Client / Company Name"
FROM
    Orders O
    LEFT JOIN Clients Cl
    ON O.ClientId = Cl.ClientId
    LEFT JOIN Companies Co
    ON O.CompanyId = Co.CompanyId
    LEFT JOIN TotalBilling B
    ON B.OrderId = O.OrderId
    LEFT JOIN TotalForwards F
    ON F.OrderId = O.OrderId
GROUP BY
    COALESCE(Cl.ClientName, Co.CompanyName)
ORDER BY
     COALESCE(Cl.ClientName, Co.CompanyName)
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef146/1/0) is a SqlFiddle showing how it would look.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it:

```
select  (case when cmp.CompanyName is null then c.ClientName else cmp.CompanyName end) "Client/Company Name"
        , sum(b.Amount) Billing
        , max(b.billingCount) QTY
        , sum(f.Amount) Forwards
        , max(f.forwardsCount) QTY
from orders o 
join Clients c
    on c.ClientId = o.ClientId
join Company cmp
    on cmp.CompanyId = o.CompanyId
join ( select OrderId , sum(amount) amount , count(*) billingCount
       from Billing b
       group by orderId
     ) b
    on b.OrderId = o.OrderId
join ( select OrderId , sum(amount(*) amount , count(*) forwardsCount
       from forwards f
       group by OrderId
      ) f
    on f.OrderId = o.OrderId
group by (case when cmp.CompanyName is null then c.ClientName else cmp.CompanyName end)
```